# about backtrack of regex

Tags: regex, backtracking

[image]

Hi all. I have a question.

In no.6 level, why backtrack to 'Welco'?

I think backtrack to 'Welcom' is correct in no.6 level.

Already been used 'Welcom' in no.4 level?

English writing is very difficult.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`[a-z]\w+\S\B`](https://regex101.com/r/cE8dI8/1) pattern is not a good pattern. Why? Because the adjoining subpatterns can match one another. That is why there are 3 backtracking steps in such a short input with such basic subpatterns.

Now, everything will become clear once you understand what the subpatterns do.

*Step 1*: We found the empty location in the string (regex engine checks each position in the input string).

*Step 2*: `[a-z]` matches the first character `W` (because the pattern is case insensitive.

*Step 3*: `\w+` matches `elcome` since this is a word character chunk of text. All these characters are added to the match value (`Welcome` already at this point! BUT there are still subpatterns to try to match. Thus, the regex engine goes on working hard.)

*Step 4*: The regex engine tries to accommodate some text for the `\S` (non-whitespace) subpattern. It backtracks, i.e. yields the last character to test if it can be matched with `\S` subpattern.

*Step 5*: The last `e` meets the requirements. Now we still have `Welcome` in the match, but the last `e` "belongs" to the `\S` subpattern.

***Step 6***: `e` matched with `\S` is not followed with a non-word boundary (as `\B`  does not match at the end of the string if the last character is a word character). This fact invalidates the `e` as the match for the `\S` subpattern. Thus, the regex engine must backtrack again to re-accommodate the value for the `\S` subpattern. `e` cannot be matched with `\S`, thus, backtracking goes to `m`. That is why the regex index at Step 6 is right after `o`.

*Step 7*: `\S` can match `m`, so now `m` "belongs" to `\S` subpattern.

*Step 8*: `\B` matches the location between `m` and `e`. Go on.

Step 9: The end of pattern is reached. Match value is returned: `Welcom`.

Comment: The whole test string is 'Welcome to my world!'. I want to match 'world!' only. I understand now. Thank you very much! Have a great day~ :)

Answer (score 1):

The `+` is greedy, it try to match everything. So Once the `\w+` matched the whole input, the engine tries to match the `\S` and fails, so it backtracks and try to match with the `\w+` one step before. It continues to do so until a match found (or not).

Comment: I'm curious why backtracks two step in No 6 level. Thank you.